# Polymer.dart: How to set read-only property to read-write attribute?

Tags: data-binding, dart, dart-polymer

I have a polymer component(lets call it **component-one**) which exposes an attribute **value**. I want to use this in another polymer component which has an Observable list property called **data**. I want to do the following:

```dart
<template repeat="{{obj in data}}">
    <component-one value="{{obj}}"></component-one>
</template>
```

But it generates error saying that there is no ***"obj="*** method.

Can somebody let me know how to data-bind a read-only property to a read-write attribute?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are running into this bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17981. This bug seems to be fixes for about 6 weeks.

You should check that you use a recent Dart version and a recent Polymer package.
If this doesn't help please add a comment.

Comment: I had to move back to Polymer 0.11.5+ to solve this problem. Also, the status of the mentioned bug is waiting. So, I think we have to wait a little longer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I verified it a while ago and that it is fixed. You could try with Polymer 0.13.0 (released today).